# Loop through all child widgets in a frame and check the type of widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I am looking to loop through all children of a frame. Then I want to be able to check the type of that widget(to see if it is a Entry). Then I want to create a new label if the child is an entry.

```
for child in frame.winfo_children():
    if child == entry :
        Label(frame, text="you did it!").grid()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
for child in frame.winfo_children():
    if child.winfo_class() == 'Entry' :
        Label(frame, text="you did it!").grid()
```